# Disable touchpad upper left corner

Tags: touchpad, synaptics, multi-touch, elantech

On my Thinkpad L13 with Elantech Touchpad running Ubuntu 20.04 I want to **disable upper left corner of touchpad** to avoid double contact when I click or keep my finger on the left mouse button and at the same time move mouse pointer. The problem is if there is a contact in the corner I can't move pointer with another finger.

**xinput** output:

```
⎡ Virtual core pointer                      id=2    [master pointer  (3)]
⎜   ↳ Virtual core XTEST pointer                id=4    [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎜   ↳ Wacom Pen and multitouch sensor Pen stylus    id=11   [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎜   ↳ Wacom Pen and multitouch sensor Finger touch  id=12   [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎜   ↳ Elan Touchpad                             id=13   [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎜   ↳ Elan TrackPoint                           id=14   [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎜   ↳ Wacom Pen and multitouch sensor Pen eraser    id=17   [slave  pointer  (2)]
```

**synclient** output related settings:

```
Parameter settings:
    LeftEdge                = 122
    RightEdge               = 2938
    TopEdge                 = 90
    BottomEdge              = 1579
    FingerLow               = 25
    FingerHigh              = 30
    MaxTapTime              = 180
    MaxTapMove              = 153
    MaxDoubleTapTime        = 180
    SingleTapTimeout        = 180
    ClickTime               = 100
    EmulateMidButtonTime    = 0
    EmulateTwoFingerMinZ    = 282
    EmulateTwoFingerMinW    = 7
    VertScrollDelta         = 200
    HorizScrollDelta        = 200
    VertEdgeScroll          = 0
    HorizEdgeScroll         = 0
    CornerCoasting          = 0
    VertTwoFingerScroll     = 1
    HorizTwoFingerScroll    = 1
    MinSpeed                = 1
    MaxSpeed                = 1.75
    AccelFactor             = 0.0573888
    TouchpadOff             = 0
    LockedDrags             = 0
    LockedDragTimeout       = 5000
    RTCornerButton          = 2
    RBCornerButton          = 3
    LTCornerButton          = 0
    LBCornerButton          = 0
    TapButton1              = 1
    TapButton2              = 0
    TapButton3              = 0
    ClickFinger1            = 1
    ClickFinger2            = 0
    ClickFinger3            = 0
    CircularScrolling       = 0
    CircScrollDelta         = 0.1
    CircScrollTrigger       = 0
    CircularPad             = 0
    PalmDetect              = 1
    PalmMinWidth            = 10
    PalmMinZ                = 200
    CoastingSpeed           = 20
    CoastingFriction        = 50
    PressureMotionMinZ      = 30
    PressureMotionMaxZ      = 160
    PressureMotionMinFactor = 1
    PressureMotionMaxFactor = 1
    ResolutionDetect        = 1
    GrabEventDevice         = 0
    TapAndDragGesture       = 1
    AreaLeftEdge            = 0
    AreaRightEdge           = 0
    AreaTopEdge             = 0
    AreaBottomEdge          = 0
    HorizHysteresis         = 17
    VertHysteresis          = 17
    ClickPad                = 1
    RightButtonAreaLeft     = 0
    RightButtonAreaRight    = 0
    RightButtonAreaTop      = 0
    RightButtonAreaBottom   = 0
    MiddleButtonAreaLeft    = 0
    MiddleButtonAreaRight   = 0
    MiddleButtonAreaTop     = 0
    MiddleButtonAreaBottom  = 0
```

I tried: **synclient AreaTopEdge=1000** but this only disables the sensitivity in the upper area but still not allow to move mouse pointer with another finger.

Any solutions?

Comment: Not exactly the solution, but just in case: did you try libinput palm-detection? Could it perhaps help you with your usecase?

Comment: Thanks. Not sure about libinput but have **Synaptics Palm Detection (374): 1**